# Flask doesn't render src's within static HTML?

Tags: python, html, caching, flask

I have a very simple flask script below that is supposed to display a dashboard containing some figures that are independent HTML files.

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():

    return send_from_directory('.', 'dashboard.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The HTML file `figure.html` displays within the dashboard, but is MASSIVELY outdated.  I can open `figure.html` manually and see that the up-to-date pie chart is different than the one being displayed.

A sample of the HTML from `dashboard.html` that is supposed to display the figure in `figure.html` is below:

```
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="chart-wrapper">
      <div class="chart-stage">
        <iframe width="100%" height="480px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="static/figure.html"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="chart-notes">
        Display Figure #1.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I suspect that this is caused by a caching issue.

Does anyone know how to make the correct `figure.html` file display?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a page refresh which ignores cached content doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> if you're using a browser like Google Chrome.

If you never want the page to be cached or to futher control how caching works, you can view this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers).

Comment: The Ctrl + F5 trick worked!

Ideally, I would want to have a programatic solution, and the issue is that even if the cache is cleared for `dashboard.html`, it will not be cleared for `figure.html`, which is what matters.